# What is the difference between {"x":1} and {x:1} inside a function context

Tags: javascript, json, function, object

This question is just to understand "How JavaScript works?" in a better way.

Tried declaring a method like below,

```
function wayOne() {
  {
    "x":1
  }
}
function wayTwo() {
  {
    x:1
  }
}
```

While function wayOne throws

> **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'**

the function wayTwo didn't throw any error.

What is the syntactical difference between these two methods

Comment: I think that way two might be being interpreted as a block not an object.

Comment: Both of your examples are fundamentally wrong. So your question can't be answered.

Comment: It is *NOT* JSON, it is a function. Property names handled like variables, not strings.

Comment: To add to @MarkusZeller's comment, there is no JSON in this question. JSON is a string, not a JS object.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON. There's no JSON involved in the sample code.

Comment: Tagged with JSON, that's why I stated the difference.

Comment: One example of a label is `x: true` which does not throw an error

Comment: Indeed @MarkusZeller. You are right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`{}` is a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block).

This makes `x:` a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

Labels have to be [identifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Identifier)

A string literal, inside a block, is just a value. Following it by a `:` is meaningless, hence: Syntax error.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin and others . With your help, I learned one new thing today